# How to add website link to erc20 token on etherscan.io

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, erc-20, etherscan

How can we add this official site link to our deployed contract? Like in the image below:
[image]

Here is my deployed contract address: https://etherscan.io/address/0xab73a739729a21b2299761408507556d2719af89#code

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which chain your token is on, so I will give an example using the Ethereum mainnet. The process is the same for other chains, just swap out the block explorer. (bscscan.com, snowtrace.io, polygonscan.com)

Send an update request to the Etherscan team using the following link: https://etherscan.io/tokenupdate

From there, enter your token address
[image]

The site will then ask you to verify you are the owner of the token: [image]

Click on the "tool" link inside the red error message. Then sign the message using the owner wallet. [image]

Then fill out the request form where you can add a link to the official website as well as social media links, etc.

The Etherscan team will review your request and send you an email asking to verify that you are indeed the owner. This process takes about a week to get the information updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to request etherscan.io to update the token information

https://etherscan.io/tokenupdate